# To print with search results highlighted

Tags: search, highlight, printing

When we search a pattern in vim, the matches are usually highlighted. However, when we print it out, the highlights disappear. I tried both `:hardcopy > my_file.pdf` and `:TOhtml`. Neither retains the highlight.

Is there any way that I can output the document with matched patterns highlighted to a pdf file?

I'm using GVim 7.4 on a Win 7 machine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
:syntax match Error "yourterm"
```

or (to ignore case and match "Yourterm", "YOURTERM", "yourTerm" etc.):

```
:syntax match Error "\cyourterm"
```

... and print with `hardcopy` - the term should be highlighted using the `Error` highlight rules. (see also [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3540/1800)).

Here's a pdf sample printed from my `vimrc`, using `:syntax match Error "Plug"`:

[image]

If the search term is already highlighted using current filetype syntax rules (so the previous command doesn't have any effect), and if you don't have a problem printing the text without those (in black-and-white, so to speak), then: `:set ft=` and then `syntax match Error "yourterm"`. You'll get black text on white background, with a touch of (probably) red - the highlighted matches.

Comment: `:syntax match Error "ur_term"` works. However, how to make it case insensitive? Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly (`\c` flag).

Comment: I remember a colour scheme specifically designed for printing, from a few years ago.  Not sure what happened to it though.  Personally I'm using `a2ps` for printing code, it fills the bill pretty well.

Comment: This one could be used for B/W printing, I think: https://github.com/plan9-for-vimspace/acme-colors